# WPF/INotifyPropertyChanged, change the value of txtA, the txtB and txtC should change automatically?

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I supposed, once i change the value of txtA, the txtB and txtC would change automatically, since i have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged for ValueA.

But they were not updated on UI. txtB was always  100, and txtC was always -50.

I don't know what's the reason.

My Xaml..

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplicationReviewDemo.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Name="txtA" Text="{Binding ValueA}" />
            <TextBox Name="txtB" Text="{Binding ValueB}" />
            <TextBox Name="txtC" Text="{Binding ValueC}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Window>
```

My code behind...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new Model();
    }
}


public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private decimal valueA;
    public decimal ValueA { get {
        return valueA;
    }
        set
        {
            valueA = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueA"));
        }
    }

    private decimal valueB;
    public decimal ValueB
    {
        get
        {
            valueB = ValueA + 100;
            return valueB;
        }
        set
        {
            valueB = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueB"));
        }
    }


    private decimal valueC;
    public decimal ValueC
    {
        get
        {
            valueC = ValueA - 50;
            return valueC;
        }
        set
        {
            valueC = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueC"));
        }
    }


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

After i add code to the set method of ValueA property, it works.

```
    public decimal ValueA { get {
        return valueA;
    }
        set
        {
            valueA = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueA"));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueB"));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueC"));
        }
    }
```

But I supposed it should be automatically refresh/updated for txtB and txtC. Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

I would approach this either as

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private decimal valueA;

    public decimal ValueA
    {
        get { return valueA; }
        set
        {
            if( valueA != value )
            {
                valueA = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueA"));
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueB"));
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueC"));
            }
        }
    }

    public decimal ValueB
    {
        get { return ValueA + 100; }
    }

    public decimal ValueC
    {
        get { return ValueA - 50; }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

or as

```
public class Model2 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private decimal valueA;
    private decimal valueB;
    private decimal valueC;

    public decimal ValueA
    {
        get { return valueA; }
        set
        {
            if( valueA != value )
            {
                valueA = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueA"));

                ValueB = value + 100;
                ValueC = value - 50;
            }
        }
    }

    public decimal ValueB
    {
        get { return valueB; }
        private set
        {
            valueB = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueB"));
        }
    }

    public decimal ValueC
    {
        get { return valueC; }
        private set
        {
            valueC = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueC"));
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box it does not know property B & C are dependent on A. You need to tell it that like you have done.

Answer (score 1):

`PropertyChanged` lets anything that is data-bound to the object that the property has changed. When you changed the value of the text box, follow the logic of the code. The set method is called for ValueA, and valueA is set to value.

```
set
{
    valueA = value;
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueA"));
}
```

However, when PropertyChanged is called, all it does is let the TextBox know that the value changed (something that it already knows, because it called the set method). The reason that the other second set method works is that it informs the other TextBoxes that their properties also changed, so they need to reflect the changes.

```
set
{
    valueA = value;
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueA"));
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueB"));
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueC"));
}
```

This lets all three TextBoxes update the display to show the new values.

Comment: I have seen many people say that your approach this is an anti-pattern.  they claim that you should instead implement a pattern where you can define the "INotify" dependencies via attributes etc.  For example, define that ValueB is dependent on ValueA rather than having ValueA have to know everything that is dependent on it.  Personally, I use your approach more often than not because it is so simple, which is why I up voted you.

Comment: @Nogusta Thank you. And also, I didn't actually write any of the code myself. If I read the question correctly, the question just asked for an explanation as to why one way worked better than the other. He wrote both snippets himself.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you are talking about is commonly refered to as "Computed" or "Calculated" properties. However it is generally recommended to make them read-only. Read-only calculated simplifies your code and means you dont need to have a backing field to store the value.

As you have worked out INotifyPropertyChanged does not "automagically" detect these dependencies. You need to explicitly fire the event based on the dependencies.

This is actually the perfect case for using ILWeaving. The reason is at compile time ILWeaving can detect these dependencies and properly fire multiple events.

For example if you use NotifyPropertyWeaver http://code.google.com/p/notifypropertyweaver/ you can write your code like this.

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public decimal ValueA { get; set; }

    public decimal ValueB
    {
        get { return ValueA + 100;}
    }

    public decimal ValueC
    {
        get { return ValueA - 50; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

and have this compiled

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    decimal valueA;

    public decimal ValueA
    {
        get { return valueA; }
        set
        {
            if (!decimal.Equals(valueA, value))
            {
                valueA = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ValueB");
                OnPropertyChanged("ValueC");
                OnPropertyChanged("ValueA");
            }
        }
    }

    public decimal ValueB
    {
        get { return ValueA + 100;}
    }

    public decimal ValueC
    {
        get { return ValueA - 50; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Note that the method OnPropertyChanged has been injected along with the three calls to is in the setter for "A".

Note that the "B" and "C" textboxes should also be read-only

```
    <TextBox Name="txtA" Text="{Binding ValueA}" />
    <TextBox Name="txtB" Text="{Binding ValueB}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    <TextBox Name="txtC" Text="{Binding ValueC}" IsReadOnly="True" />
```